# Excel VBA - Dynamic Array not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, array

I am trying to make an array that stores all of the values in Column A from "Workbook B" so I can then reference and see if a cell's value is in that array in Column A from "Workbook A".

This is what I have so far for that array:

```
Dim StrArray() As String
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim X As Long

Workbooks.Open Filename:="filepath", ReadOnly:=True

With Workbooks("file").Worksheets("sheet")
    TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim StrArray(1 To TotalRows)
    For X = 2 To TotalRows
        StrArray(X) = Cells(X, 1).Value
    Next X
End With
```

This part of the array works just fine, I confirmed it's working correctly by displaying all of the values in the array in an MsgBox.
The problem comes when I try to reference this array in "Workbook A" to check if a cell's value is in that array.

This is what I have for that code:

```
For RowCounter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If IsInArray(Range("B" & RowCounter).Value, StrArray) Then
        Range("K" & RowCounter).Value = "MATCH"
    End If
Next RowCounter

Workbooks("file").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Here is the function I am using:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

It does not put the "MATCH" value in column K. I tried troubleshooting by putting a MsgBox in the If statement to see if it's matching the value to the array, and it gave me a never ending loop of the MsgBox. If it matters, there is currently text in column K that this code is writing over.

Comment: I have two news for you. The good news is that the word "MATCH" appears in the right cells. The bad news is that saving the file with `SaveChanges:=False` cancels all of these changes. (This is what I saw in these code snippets - maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: By the way, extract values into an array and looking there is not a very bad idea. However, if you still open the "sheet" of the workbook "filepath" and can get a range up to TotalRows, then it makes sense to use the [**WorksheetFunction.Match method**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match#example) - they say it's much faster. (There are many lines in this example, you will only need 4 - replace the text of your `IsInArray()` function with them)

Answer (score 0):

If I were solving such a problem, I would refuse to use an array in favor of the built-in [**MATCH method**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match):

```
Sub markCellsIfPresent()
Const DICTIONARY_WORKBOOK As String = "filepath"
Const DICTIONARY_WORKSHEET = "sheet"
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim rValidate As Range
Dim oCell As Range
Dim wbDictionary As Workbook
Dim wsDictionary As Worksheet
Dim rDictionary As Range
Dim searchRes As Variant

    Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
    Set rValidate = Application.Intersect(wsActive.UsedRange, wsActive.Columns(2))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbDictionary = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=DICTIONARY_WORKBOOK, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsDictionary = wbDictionary.Worksheets(DICTIONARY_WORKSHEET)
    Set rDictionary = Application.Intersect(wsDictionary.UsedRange, wsDictionary.Columns(1))
        
    For Each oCell In rValidate.Cells
        searchRes = Application.Match(oCell.Text, rDictionary, 0)
        If Not IsError(searchRes) Then
Rem oCell in column B (2), we set mark to column K (11), so offset is 11-2=9
           oCell.Offset(0, 9).value = "MATCH"
        End If
    Next oCell
   
    wbDictionary.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Of course, the real code should be longer - for example, you need to check if the workbook "filepath" exists and is open, if it has a sheet named "sheet" in it, if there is data there, and more

This code solves the problem, but does not answer your question about using an array for this purpose.

The array code will be a bit longer because we need a helper procedure to fill it and a function to search it.

```
Sub markCellsWithArray()
Const DICTIONARY_WORKBOOK As String = "filepath"
Const DICTIONARY_WORKSHEET = "sheet"
Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Dim rValidate As Range
Dim oCell As Range
Dim wbDictionary As Workbook
Dim wsDictionary As Worksheet
Dim rDictionary As Range
Dim StrArray As Variant

    Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
    Set rValidate = Application.Intersect(wsActive.UsedRange, wsActive.Columns(2))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wbDictionary = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=DICTIONARY_WORKBOOK, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wsDictionary = wbDictionary.Worksheets(DICTIONARY_WORKSHEET)
    Set rDictionary = Application.Intersect(wsDictionary.UsedRange, wsDictionary.Columns(1))
Rem Collect values from dictionary to array (skip empty cells)
    StrArray = Array()
    For Each oCell In rDictionary.Cells
        If Not Trim(oCell.Text) = vbNullString Then Call AddIfNeed(Trim(oCell.Text), StrArray)
    Next oCell
    wbDictionary.Close
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Rem Mark cells in active sheet
    For Each oCell In rValidate.Cells
        If IsInArray(Trim(oCell.Text), StrArray) Then
           oCell.Offset(0, 9).value = "MATCH"
        End If
    Next oCell
End Sub
Sub AddIfNeed(ByVal key As String, aData As Variant)
Dim l&, r&, m&, N&, i&
    l = LBound(aData)
    r = UBound(aData) + 1
    N = r
    While (l < r)
        m = l + Int((r - l) / 2)
        If aData(m) < key Then l = m + 1 Else r = m
    Wend
    If r = N Then   ' Add to end of set
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        aData(N) = key
    ElseIf aData(r) = key Then
' Already in the set, do nothing
    Else    ' Insert to set in correct place
        ReDim Preserve aData(0 To N)
        For i = N - 1 To r Step -1
            aData(i + 1) = aData(i)
        Next i
        aData(r) = key
    End If
End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(ByVal stringToBeFound As String, aData As Variant) As Boolean
Dim l&, r&, m&, N&, i&
    l = LBound(aData)
    r = UBound(aData) + 1
    N = r
    While (l < r)
        m = l + Int((r - l) / 2)
        If aData(m) < stringToBeFound Then l = m + 1 Else r = m
    Wend
    If r = N Then   ' Add to end of set
        IsInArray = False
    Else
        IsInArray = (aData(r) = stringToBeFound)    ' TRUE if found
    End If
End Function
```

The trick of the helper code is to use a [**binary search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which is much faster than the [**linear search**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) you use when going through an unsorted array element by element.

To implement this trick without helper code, you could use a [**Dictionary object**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object#methods) - it's all there already and you don't have to worry about your own implementation of the classic algorithms.

However, test both procedures on sufficiently large datasets and see how the array algorithm outperforms the built-in MATCH method.

Answer (score 0):

JohnSUN's code works well, but I also did figure out how to get the array path to work.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="filepath", ReadOnly:=True

    With Workbooks("filename").Worksheets("sheetname")
        TotalRows = Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim StrArray(1 To TotalRows)
        For X = 2 To TotalRows
            StrArray(X) = Cells(X, 1).Value
        Next X
    End With

    Workbooks("filename").Close SaveChanges:=False

    ActWS.Activate

    'Adds MATCH to applicable rows
    For RowCounter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsInArray(Range("B" & RowCounter).Value, StrArray) Then
            Range("K" & RowCounter).Value = "MATCH"
        End If
    Next RowCounter
End If
```

The problem was when "MATCH" was being applied, it was putting it in the wrong file. So I had to reactivate the file I wanted it in before the code was executed.